# sending emails from Episerver through XForm

Tags: email, smtp, xforms, episerver

Attempting to send email from episerver xform. What else needs to be setup from my machine hosting the app besides from adding this in the web.config file?
Thanks.

> ```
> <mailSettings>
>   <smtp deliveryMethod='PickupDirectoryFromIis'>
>     <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\temp" />
>   </smtp>
> </mailSettings>
>    </system.net>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the delivermethod to "SpecifiedPickupDirectory" instead of "PickupDirectoryFromIis".

PickupDirectoryFromIis doesn't have an option to specify a pickupDirectoryLocation.

As stated at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpdeliverymethod(v=vs.110).aspx):

> PickupDirectoryFromIis:
> Email is copied to the pickup directory used by a local Internet Information Services (IIS) for delivery.
>
> SpecifiedPickupDirectory: Email is copied to the directory specified by the SmtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation property for delivery by an external application.

Comment: Thanks jontem. I changed to this: `<mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod='SpecifiedPickupDirectory'>
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\temp" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>` but the emails are still neither being sent (even if I get no error message), nor is a copy placed in the temp folder as instructed in config. I think something must be missing.

Comment: Do i need to setup telnet to work properly on my pc?At the moment, this `telnet bla@gmail.com 25` gives an error like
"Connecting To bla@gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed"

Comment: Does the account running the AppPool have the permission to write to that directory? 

I don't think that is the correct adress to gmail:s SMTP service. Many ISP:s are also blocking outgoing traffic on port 25.

Comment: Yes, the account has permissions to write to that directory. I am mostly interested in actually sending emails; saving copies of those emails on my local PC are a secondary concern, mainly to help me check the mechanism functions correctly up to a stage of handling the message locally before actually sending it to the remote server. I am not sure if this is how I should check it. Appreciate any tips or advice to help me get going.